# regular expression issue using boost::regex

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to construct a regular expression in C++ using `boost::regex` that would match word starting with `MOV` or `JMP` following by `:\\d:\\d-\\d:\\d`.

For example, `MOV:1:2-3:4` or `JMP:2:2-3:5`.

I tried with expression as `(MOV|JMP):\\d:\\d-\\d:\\d`, but it is evaluating false to above two examples.

I have two questions:

1. What is wrong in above expression?
2. What would be regular expression if i want to ignore case for MOV and JMP?

Comment: Can you not use std::regex for some reason? [C++ regex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/)

Comment: the gcc on my box does not support c++ regex. But does c++ regex evaluates above expression to true for the given examples?

Answer (score 0):

The following works perfectly for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   boost::regex it("(MOV|JMP):\\d:\\d-\\d:\\d");

   bool matches = boost::regex_match("MOV:1:2-3:4", it);

   std::cout << matches << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Here's the compilation:

```
svengali ~ % g++ main.c -lboost_regex
svengali ~ % a.out
1
svengali /tmp % g++ --version
g++ (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2
```

How are you entering the expression?  If it's not a string literal, you may not need to escape the backslash.